# Issue facing with Laravel eloquent whereIn condition

Tags: laravel-5

I am unable to fetch data using whereIn eloquent condition in `laravel` but same I can fetch all data without condition. how can I resolve this?

```
public function getOrders()
 {  
     $customerNumberArr = Session::get('sales_customer');   
     $orderFormList =   OrderForm::whereIn("CUSTOMER_NUMBER", $customerNumberArr)  
                             ->orderBy('id', 'desc')  
                             ->paginate(Config::get('common.per_page'));   
    return View::make('orderForms')->with('orderFormList',$orderFormList );
  }
```

Comment: what does dd($customerNumberArr) show?

Comment: Initially, try to hardcode an array with few elements and see if you're getting any data, also use DB::getQueryLog() to see what query is been generated.

Comment: CUSTOMER_NUMBER is it a constant or just a string value?